# What is "additional line load" [N/mm] for the Ariane 5 launch vehicle?

Tags: launch-vehicle, ariane, design

In the textbook [*Spacecraft Systems Engineering*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Spacecraft+Systems+Engineering%2C+4th+Edition-p-9780470750124) 4th ed. page 14, table 2.1 ("Acceleration values for the Ariane 5 launch vehicle") provides data on the loading of the Ariane 5 spacecraft. One of the columns listed is "Additional line load" given in units of N/mm. However, the meaning of this field isn't actually described.

> Table 2.1 shows the design loads that a satellite must achieve associated with various mission events for the Ariane 5 launch vehicle[...].
>
> [image: Table 2.1 of Spacecraft Systems Engineering]
>
> *Table 2.1: Acceleration values for the Ariane 5 launch vehicle [3].*

No other context is provided to explain or generalize these terms. The table is reproduced as best I can in MathJax, but differs non-critically from print copy.

What is the line load "additional" with respect to (some static load?), and more generally, how should it be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NASA document, "[Preliminary In-Flight Loads Analysis of In-Line Launch Vehicles Using the VLOADS 1.4 Program](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980201045.pdf)", has a nice answer for you:

*Line loads are measures of load intensity which are derived from the stress equations for a monocoque shell with an applied axial force, pressure, and bending
moment. Line loads, measured in pounds per inch, are calculated by dividing the longitudinal monocoque shell stress by a unit thickness.* (page  5).

Don't be fooled by the units, btw: "pounds/inch" really means "pound-force per inch"; your book uses SI units. If you're capable of studying that book, you can do the conversion by yourself. Godspeed with studying !

Comment: This is super helpful and exactly what I needed! Thank you. Can I ask how you found this, so I can find similar reference documents in the future?

Comment: @Aza You'll be surprised: I had a hunch of what line load was, but to be sure I googled it, hoping to find a NASA document - using a few moderately advanced search options of the engine, however. IIRC the search text was "line load" site:nasa.gov (the parentheses are there to force google to only look for exact occurrences, in that order, of the words).