# How to do Preliminary Analysis of Spacecraft Primary Structure?

Tags: spacecraft, design, launch-vehicle, structural-design, analysis

I'm looking for specifics as to how preliminary analysis on spacecraft primary structure is performed (prior to CLA).

I understand LV providers include CG load factors in their user manuals, but how exactly is this information used? Is it as simple as creating a FEM, fixing the spacecraft base (how it would be secured to the LV), and then applying the different loads through the corresponding axes?

For example, the below table is taken from *ECSS-E-HB-32-26A: Spacecraft Mechanical Loads Analysis Handbook* for Ariane 5. Would I step through each flight phase and apply the combination of longitudinal and lateral accelerations? What is meant by "static" acceleration here and what is the additional line load?

[image]

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38331/what-is-additional-line-load-n-mm-for-the-ariane-5-launch-vehicle?rq=1      https://standards.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/standards/NASA/A/0/nasa-std-5002a.pdf

Comment: @Puffin, thanks for the first link. The second, however (NASA-STD-5002), I have read and doesn't answer my question on how these loads are actually used in practice.